# Ordering of array dimensions

Tags: arrays, fortran

Given the following code:

```
integer, parameter :: n = 10000
integer, parameter :: m = 3

real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: arr

! First way
allocate(arr(n,m))

! Second way
allocate(arr(m,n))
```

What is the "best" way to allocate `arr` when there is a large difference in the two dimensions, the first way or the second way? Does it matter, or is it something that is strongly dependent on how `arr` will be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortran is [column-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order), i.e. the first dimension changes the fastest.

The optimal choice of dimensions depends on your problem: 
If `arr` is a list of coordinates in a 3D space, and you commonly operate on these coordinates, you should probably choose the second option:

```
allocate(arr(m,n))
arr(:,1) = [x, y, z]
! ...
```

Then, you have a contiguous layout for each coordinate.

If you have three vectors with a length of `n = 10000` instead (e.g. three right-hand-sides), option one would give you contiguous chunks for each vector.

In conclusion: it depends what you are trying to do.

Comment: It is for a list of 3D coordinates, and I kind of thought that the second option would be the way to go, but its nice to have some confirmation. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score -1):

If there is a difference, it is a minor one related to the characteristics of sequential memory access, memory fetch optimizations, and maybe caching.

Otherwise, don't worry about it.  Just make the program work correctly.  If somehow a few more nanoseconds of performance need to be squeezed out of it, well, there are undoubtedly better places to expend mental energy to get it.

If you are passing slices of the array to a function, then the difference matters greatly.

Comment: There is a huge difference! Strided memory access can ruin the overall performance!

Comment: @AlexanderVogt:  It is extremely unlikely to have any measurable effect.  Most programs will be doing far more than only reading or writing an array:  even with it perfectly laid out, other memory accesses will totally undermine any would-be savings.

Comment: Sorry, but his is simply not true. Fortran is typically performing number-crunching on vectors and arrays and accessing that memory heavily impacts performance. For the numerical core there are usually only very few other operations.

Comment: Hager et al. provide a comprehensive and extensive treatise of this matter in their book [Introduction to High Performance Computing for Scientists and Engineers](https://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781439811924).

Comment: Nevertheless, when you try to optimize these routines you try to utilize cache lines to improve performance... You try to update cells that are contiguous in memory, and do all you can do to have them close-by. You are right in that this is often not possible, but you should still try to keep everything contiguous! Take a look at (highly optimized) linear algebra routines and how they try to optimize performance.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt:  It would be great to have such a simple problem to solve and for that such optimization is likely to be fruitful.  Alas, the vast collection of real world problems are not so orderly.

Comment: @wallyk I tend to agree with Alexander Vogt in this regard. This question arose from the standpoint of writing a molecular dynamics simulation code. Here, there are typically thousands to millions of particles that need to have their position and momentum updated every single time step for a very large number of time steps. Even small improvements per time step by optimizing cache usage in the above way can make the code significantly more usable for a given study.